# Eclipse Internal Browser doesn't apply HTML tags

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I've created a simple servlet in Java and showing its HTML output in Eclipse internal browser.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("<h3> Hello World </h3>");
    }
```

But the output is like this :
[image]

Why doesn't apply `<h3>` tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to set response content type:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
{ 
     response.setContentType("text/html");

     PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

     writer.println("<h3> Hello World </h3>");



}
```